# AngularJS getting $event from a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Seems pretty simple, but I can't get $event to bubble up from my directive.  When `test` gets called from `cb-click`, `$event` is undefined, but outside of a directive (via html), it's the event object.

If I use a linking function (not included in my fiddle), I can get `$event`, but I can't $parse/$eval it against the right scope.

http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/KgcGY/

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="x">
    <!-- via directive -->
    <checkbox cb-model="y" cb-click="test($event, b)"></checkbox>
    <!-- via html -->
    <div><input id="c2" type="checkbox" ng-model="x" ng-click="test($event, 'a')"> <label for="c2">{{x}}</label></div> 
</div>
```

-

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('checkbox', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            cbModel: '=',
            cbClick: '&'
        },
        template: '<div><input id="c1" type="checkbox" ng-model="cbModel" ng-click="cbClick($event, \'a\')"> <label for="c1">{{cbModel}}</label></div>'
    };
});

app.controller('x', function x($scope) {
    $scope.x = true;
    $scope.y = true;
    $scope.test = function (ev, b) {
        console.log('test called, ev is', ev, 'b is', b);
        return 'xyz';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use this syntax inside your directive:

```
ng-click="cbClick({ev: $event, b:\'a\'})
```

With this HTML:

```
cb-click="test(ev, b)"
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/uvuJX/)

From the [directives page](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), section "Directive Definition Object":

> Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolated scope via an expression and to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a map of local variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For example, if the expression is `increment(amount)` then we can specify the amount value by calling the `localFn` as `localFn({amount: 22})`

Comment: @Langdon, a working example in the docs would be more helpful though.  A lot of people miss this.  (I certainly didn't get it the first few times I read it.)  I included the documentation reference just so people could see where it is (briefly) mentioned in the docs.

Comment: You mean where it *was* in the docs!  Saw it a few weeks ago, but it's gone now.  Long live SO.