# Access attribute value inside non-directive controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

HTML content,

```
<button data-href="helloworld">Show href Value</button>
```

Js content,

```
$("body").on('click', 'button', function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("data-href"));
});
```

This prints

```
helloworld
```

in the console.
I am migrating the above code to angularjs,

```
<div ng-controller="hello">
  <button data-href="helloworld">Show href Value</button>
</div>

var app = angular.module('app',  []);

app.controller("hello", function(){
  //someone help me with the services that are to be injected and 
  //and what logic goes here to print the data-href attribute value
})
```

Can someone help me with the `hello` controller function arguments and contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are switching over to AngularJS you will have to start rethinking your app entirely -- it's difficult to make a complete overhaul from an existing app that is using selection and DOM manipulation.  Angular is typically used to avoid these.  Thus, you should ask yourself *why* you need to bind to an event rather than using data bindings / the view model.

That's too much to get into here, so to solve your immediate problem you could use a directive.

```
<button show-href="helloworld">Show href Value</button>

// `data-` prefixes stripped from directives as part of Angular normalization
app.directive("showHref", function () {
    return function (scope, elem, attr) {
        elem.bind("click", function () {
            console.log(attr.showHref);
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular way would be to define value in controller scope

```
<button data-href="{{myUrl}}" ng-click="helloClick()">Show href Value</button>
....
app.controller("hello", function($scope){
     $scope.myUrl = 'helloworld';
     $scope.helloClick = function(){
          console.log($scope.myUrl);
     }
})
```

However if you really need to define `data-href` from html and get access to it in angular code that you need to consider using a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) instead of a controller

Comment: Would need to be `ng-click="helloClick()"`

Answer (score 0):

```
var $scope;
var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.clickEvent = function(obj) {

        // Log the obj to see everything
        console.log(obj);

        // Alert just the data value
        alert(obj.target.attributes.data.value);

    }
};
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="miniapp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <a ng-click="clickEvent($event)" class="exampleClass" id="exampleID" data="exampleData" href="">Click Me</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/FAeJq/)